# Paypal JavaScript SDK: What return values are expected by the Button functions, e.g. onApprove?

Tags: paypal

The docs are not talking about return values at all.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#buttons

I can only guess based on the examples:

- **createOrder**: should return the orderID (there is a helpful error message from the library / server if you don't)
- **onApprove**: ?

The example contains a return statement, but does not return anything?

```
  onApprove: function(data, actions)  {
    // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details)  {
      // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
      alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return ends the function, and what is important is not the return's value but that you have ended with a capture and the correct behavior after a capture.

A client side capture is simple, per your example.

A proper server side capture should handle three situations based on the server's response, per the example at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link to the example. Guess I was mainly confused by the style. I usually expect `doSomethingWithoutReturnValue(); return;` for functions without return value.